# exit status of piped command line in ksh

Tags: shell, pipe, ksh

In `bash`, from environment variable `$PIPESTATUS` we can retrieve exit staus of piped command line like below.

```
$ echo "some string" | grep x | tee some.tmp ; echo ${PIPESTATUS[1]}
1
```

However if I am on `ksh` I need to something like below to get exit status. I searched for it to get something like below.

```
$ getme=`((echo "some string" | grep x 3>&- 4>&- ; echo $? >&4) | tee some.tmp 1>&3 3>&- 4>&- ) 4>&1` ; echo $getme
1


$ getme=`((echo "some string " | grep me 3>&- 4>&- ; echo $? >&4) | tee some.tmp 1>&3 3>&- 4>&- ) 4>&1` ; echo $getme
0
```

Is there a simpler form to above one in `ksh` to retrieve exit status in piped command line?. And how to interprit above line. I do know little on subshell & usage of 4 as descriptor.
Redirection part is little hart to interprit

Answer (score 2):

`$?` does not suite ?

```
echo "some string" | grep x | tee some.tmp ; echo "Returncode: $?"
```

or you need specific error code for each pipe

you can also try using `set` options

> -e
>
> Unless contained in a || or && command, or  the  commandfollowing   an  if  while  or  until  command  or  in the pipeline following !, if a command has a non-zero  exit status,  execute the  ERR trap, if set, and exit.  This mode is disabled while reading profiles.
>
> -o  pipefail
>
> A pipeline will not complete  until  all components  of    the  pipeline have completed, and the return value will be the value of the last  non-zero  command  to fail or zero if no command has failed.

Comment: In above case, $? will print 0 as last executed command i.e., 'tee' will be success & I intended to get exec status of grep operation not tee operation. How do achieve with pipefail / set -e in ksh which you mentioned?

Comment: i thing you need to set the option before the use of the pipe and that will define the behavior of the shell with pipe, by default, goes to the end if possible even with intermediate error occuring. So if set the option to pipe , if you receive a RC of 0, all the pipe work fine, if not, you need to make an iteratif test to find the failing one or flag system (like tee_ing every step)